# C++ and - (unsigned int)

Tags: c++

Why does the following line

```
auto k = -10u;
```

return k = 4294967286 ? Shouldn't it typecast - 10unsigned to a signed integer?

Comment: Why would the *unary* `-` change the type of its operand? All other operators applied to some numerical type return that same type.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, why not?

Comment: Because most C++ operators give a result of the same type as that of their operand. Why would you make an exception for unary `-`; isn't C++ already too complex?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. It shouldn't.

-(unsigned type) is of unsigned type.

Any operator applied to built-in integers have result of same type